# How online shopping works in this case?

Tags: php, forms, paypal, shopping-cart

I would like to create a web form for the buyer to fill and then a direction to `Paypal` to pay the item, then comeback to the page and if the purchase is approved it submits the form and wait send me an email with its details.

I know how to create the form but front-end, and also I know how to send a php email to submit the form. But what about the payment part ?!

Can someone explain me how it works.

Is it possible to create something like this?
Any tutorial or similar example, links would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Paypal API

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside

When the user successfully completes the transaction the result is sent back to the page, you then check if the result was successful, if so onwards with whatever code.